# SQL column of type varchar creates � symbols when read into SAS

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, sas, ssms

I am reading data into SAS from a SQL table using a basic libname and data step. However, certain 'special characters' - in this case a dash - are read as a black diamond with a question mark: `�`

I am aware that this is caused by an encoding issue - the SQL column has a `varchar` datatype, and SAS cannot read this properly (details of why this happens would be appreciated). A solution I am aware of is changing the column to type `nvarchar`; however, I do not own the database so cannot change this.

I have tried various options relating to encoding, inencoding and outencoding (in the libname and data step) but cannot get the right combination, if there is one.

My current workaround is to create a view which uses `CAST` to convert the data type, and reading the view into SAS. However, I am convinced there must be a coding solution - does anyone know?

Comment: What encoding is your SAS session using?  What encoding did you tell it to use for the connection to SQL Server?

Comment: Note that the character in the database is not an ASCII code dash.  It is probably some Unicode string for an en-dash or em-dash symbol.

Comment: "varchar datatype, which handles ASCII characters": No, varchar handles characters from the associated collation—very unlikely to be ASCII. The code you used to query the database should be using that when converting bytes to Unicode.

Comment: [This link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/write-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) was what told me it would be ASCII (3rd answer down) and was the first thing Google brought up for me, I can see after some more googling that it isn't right though... The collation in SQL is 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' and the SAS session encoding is using UTF-8. The libname to connect to SQL doesn't specify the encoding and I'm not sure how to check - which may well be my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII, "U+FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" is used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character. If this is the only character causing you issues, you can simply convert it into a dash.

As an example, let's replace � values with a dash:

```
data have;
    length character $20.;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    input character$;
    datalines;
Sugar�free
Camera�ready
Custom�built
;
run;

data want;
    set have;

    character = tranwrd(character, '�', '-');
run;
```

If that doesn't work, here is an alternative option.

**Step 1: Find a single example of the character and get its ASCII hex code**

```
data hex_code;
    set have(obs=1);
    ascii_hex = put(substr(character, 6, 1), $hex.);
run;
```

In this case, the hex code is `1A`. We can use this as a hex literal to replace the offending character.

**Step 2: Use `tranwrd` with the hex literal that you found**

SAS will automatically understand `'1A'x` as a hex value, and will search for it in the string. If it is found, `tranwrd` will replace all instances with a dash.

```
data want;
    set have;

    character = tranwrd(character, '1A'x, '-');
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately there is no guarantee that the right character will _always_ be a dash - it happens to be so in all the cases I've found so far, but I would prefer a more all-encompassing solution (or a definitive/well-supported statement that there is not one).

Comment: In this case, it would be best to contact SAS technical support: https://support.sas.com/en/technical-support/contact-sas.html. They'll have someone who is an expert in handling these exact situations get a hold of you and help you resolve it. Encoding issues between databases can be very tricky sometimes.